# file_exists() returns false, even for paths that do exist

Tags: php, html, displayobject

OK programmers, I'd like to figure this one out before the New Year. I want to display a photo only if it exists, otherwise use a default photo. Here is my code that always correctly returns "File Exists"

```
<?php 
    $photolocation = '../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/Joe Smith.jpg';
    if (!file_exists($photolocation))
    {
        echo "File exists";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "File does not exist";
    }
?>
```

When I change the `photolocation` to:

`$photolocation = '../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/XXX Smith.jpg';`

I incorrectly get "File exists".

I can't figure out why the condition !file_exists  always returns a positive value.

Comment: You realise that you're asking your `if` to assess whether the file does ***not*** exist? Therefore you should only get `file exists` when the file does *not* exist...unless I'm really misunderstanding something about the `file_exists()` function.

Comment: @DavidThomas is right. Remove the NOT `!` from the if condition

Comment: I agree with @DavidThomas and @ xbonez. The thing is, this also means than neither of your paths work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be:

```
<?php 
    $photolocation = '../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/XXX Smith.jpg';

    if (file_exists($photolocation))
    {
        echo "File exists";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "File does not exist";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think my problem might be related to if the server does NOT allow to follow symbolic links.  Does this make sense?  It seems like such a simple issue...but I have wasted days on it.

Comment: @DoubleA can you edit your question to note what part of `$photolocation` is a symbolic link?  Also, it would help if you include the output of `getcwd()`.

Comment: what os / web server are you running?